# How does python print unicode strings and lists?

Tags: python, printing, unicode-string

What is the difference between the following two python outputs using print?

The first code

```
s=u'String'
print s
```

prints the following message.

`String`

The second code

```
sl={}
sl[u'String']=u'String'
print sl
```

prints a different message.

```
{u'String': u'String'}
```

Why are the unicode tags removed in the first scenario, but not the second.

Also, if I use IDLE and do not use print I get `u'String'`, as shown below:

```
>>> s=u'String'
>>> s
u'String'
```

However, if I put the same two lines in `file.py` and run `python file.py` I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For your first piece of code you are printing a string hence why it prints as expected.

For your second piece of code:

```
sl={}
```

Defines sl as a dictionary and

```
sl[u'String']=u'String'
```

adds a key-value pair to the dictionary. So when you print sl it is printing the key:value pairs for all of the dictionary.

This may help you understand

```
>>> x = {}
>>> x[1] = "Hello"
>>> x[2] = "Bye"
>>> print x
{1: 'Hello', 2: 'Bye'}
>>>
```

Comment: Thank, you. I just learned the differences between tuples, lists and dictionaries. At least I know what the code is doing now. However, my original question was about the behavior of printing operation. Why does print convert unicode strings to ASCII, but it does not do so for tuples, lists, or dictionaries?